# QGIS 3.01 (Mac) Can not filter legend items in Atlas

Tags: print-composer, qgis-3, atlas

I am not sure if this is a bug or if I have missed something that has changed in 3.0.  The issue is that in the composer/atlas when I display the item properties of the legend all of the 'tools' are greyed out:

[image]

I can't figure out how to remove irrelevant entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to uncheck `Auto update` to activate the buttons under the legend.

With `Auto update`:

[image]

After uncheck `Auto update`:

[image]